# Angular 5 ngModel ngFor not working with trackBy

Tags: angular

This is my html

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let bookInstance of bookInstanceList; trackBy: trackByBookList;">
     <label for="status">Status</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" placeholder="Status of the book" [(ngModel)]="bookInstance.status" name="status" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my typescript

```
private bookInstanceList = [
      {
        "status": "Not Available",
      },
      {
        "status": "I am  Available",
      }
    ];

  trackByBookList(index: number, bookInstance: any): any {
    return index;
  }
```

I followed many tutorials on trackBy but i am still not able to get the input field of the first input to be "Not Available" and the 2nd one to be "Available". I think it is because i am using input tags? I am using angular 5

Comment: did u make the variable public

Comment: Code seems working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j4l6rd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html here

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka yes i did\

Comment: @PardeepJain not sure why its not working on mine. I am using bootstrap 4 input field.

Comment: @Desmond - Maybe because your HTML is inside a `form` tag.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes i have a form tag outside. How do i solve this?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Good point noted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `input` fields in a `form` tag, make sure that each field has a unique `name` (except for a group of radio buttons, where the radio input elements share the same name):

```
<div *ngFor="let bookInstance of bookInstanceList; let i=index; trackBy: trackByBookList;">
    <label>Status
        <input type="text" [name]="'status_' + i" [(ngModel)]="bookInstance.status" ...>
    </label>
</div>
```

You may also consider removing the `id` attribute. Each `id` should be unique, which is not the case in your original code.